# Make page mobile friendly?

Tags: html, css, zooming, mobile-website

I have a lot of webpages, and a few websites. The problem is, I am a begginner. I use basic html5 & css3 and I don't know how can I make them zoom in, zoom out and mobile friendly. For example, here's one of my pages and one of my websites, where you can see there's a little problem with zooming in and out, and it's not mobile friendly at all:

https://mitkovtori.github.io/

https://mitko-vtori-world.github.io/Mitko-Vtori-World/

So, is there a way to fix it for all sizes, or something like recreating for mobile, etc..?

I've tried to use percents "%" for sizes, like for example:

<width="25%">

I've also tried with pixels "25px".
With just numbers "25".

But whatever I do, there's always problem with zooming In, out and mobile devices.

The code is 100% open source, so you can go around my trash code and try find where is my mistake.

The repos for the two sites I share in the beggining:
https://github.com/MitkoVtori/MitkoVtori.github.io

https://github.com/Mitko-Vtori-World/Mitko-Vtori-World

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use media query for example if you want to style  at screen size below 1023px you need to add at bottom of you css file like this

```
@media(max-width:1023px){ 
   /* your code will be here */
   .navbar{
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }
}
```

then again if you want at below 768

```
@media(max-width:768px){ 
       /* your code will be here */
       .navbar{
            padding: 10px 15px;
        }
    }
```

a similar pattern for big and small screens